# Moduli space of flat connections over a torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces

Let us fix a principal bundle $G\hookrightarrow P\to T^{2}$, where $T^{2}$ is a torus. Is the moduli space of  flat connections on $P$ known? At least, it is known for some particular gauge groups, like for examples $U(1)$ or $SU(2)$?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "known"? The moduli space of flat $G$-connections on a torus is the space $\{ (g, h) \in G^2 : gh = hg \}$ of commuting pairs of elements of $G$ ($g, h$ are given by monodromy around a pair of generators of $\pi_1$) modulo the action of $G$ given by simultaneous conjugation. What does it mean to know this space?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks. What I meant is, is it a known manifold? From your answer I guess that that is indeed the case. Can you give a reference about this result?

Comment: It is not a manifold in general. Lots of stuff is known about these sorts of spaces; one keyword you can use is "character variety."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: the fact that it is or it is not a manifold depends then only on the group $G$ right? From String-Theory predictions it should be a particular manifold, or at least an appropriate subspace of an homogeneous manifold.

Comment: For the examples $U(1)$ and $SU(2)$, the answer is pretty easy to work out by hand.  In general, this moduli space is homeomorphic to Hom($\mathbb{Z}^2, G)/G$ (via the holonomy map) and for $G$ abelian (e.g. $U(1)$) we just get $G\times G$.  For $SU(2)$, any commuting pair of matrices is simultaneously diagonalizable, and from this you can explicitly describe Hom$(\mathbb{Z}^2, SU(2))/SU(2)$ as a 2-dimensional sphere (up to homeomorphism).  Working this out explicitly in terms of eigenvalues of the matrices is a nice exercise.

Comment: @DanRamras: Thanks! In fact both of your calculations are consistent with the prediction from Heterotic String Theory. Do you have any particular reference about this?

Comment: I put a brief discussion of the unitary case Section 5.1 of my paper "The stable moduli space of flat connections over a surface," Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 363 (2011), no. 1, 1061-1100. arXiv:0810.4882.  (It's probably written out in other places also.)  For the case of $SU(n)$ there is a discussion in Adem-Cohen-Gomez "Stable splittings, spaces of representations and almost commuting elements in Lie groups," Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society / Volume 149 / Issue 03 / November 2010, pp 455-490 (http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0735).

Comment: @Bilteral Where can one read about these predictions from Heterotic String Theory?

Comment: @DanRamras About this particular prediction, it is an ongoing project, not yet published. Anyway, the general story is the following: the moduli space of the compactification space of M/String-theory is closely related to the geometry of the non-linear sigma-model of the corresponding effective Supergravity. The different scalar geometries in Supergravity have been already classified and thus this information can be used to extract information about the moduli space of the compactification manifold. Continued.

Comment: There are no standard references to see this identifications in detail, but you can check for example:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.5103.pdf

to get an idea of what is going on in the case of Calabi-Yau compactifications, where the Special Kahler geometry of their moduli space matches in a very precise way the Special Kahler and Quaternionic Kahler geometries of N=2, d=4 Supergravity. This gave rise to the "r" and "c" maps, which encode non-trivial relations between Special and Quaternionic geometry, very hard to find without the input from Supergravity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Almost commuting elements in compact Lie groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907007) by Borel, Freedman, and Morgan.

"We describe the components of the moduli space of conjugacy classes of commuting pairs and triples of elements in a compact Lie group. This description is in terms of the extended Dynkin diagram of the simply connected cover, together with the coroot integers and the action of the fundamental group."