# Moduli space of flat connections of Lie group over a 2-torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, character-varieties

We know that the moduli space of SU($N$) principal bundle's flat connections over a torus, is equivalent to a complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^{N-1}$
Namely,
$$
M_{\rm flat}=\mathbb{E} / {S}_N = \mathbb{P}^{N-1}
$$
where $\mathbb{E}$ is given by
$$ 
\mathbb E := \left\{ (\phi_1,\cdots, \phi_N)  \equiv {(\mathbb  T^2)}^N; \text{ subject to a constrain }\sum_i \phi_i=0 \right\} . 
$$
while the ${S}_N$ is the symmetric group usually denoted as $S_N$ (the Weyl group of SU$(N)$).

I learned the answer from the post and Lisa Jeffrey's note:  [Moduli space of flat connections over a Riemann surface](https://mathoverflow.net/q/313889/27004)

My questions

> - what is the moduli space of SO(N) principal bundle's flat connections over a 2-torus?
> - what is the moduli space of PSU(N) principal bundle's flat connections over a 2-torus?

If this is too general, we can focus on the case: SO(3)=PSU(2).

Thank you for the kind comments and helps!

---

Some Refs I found:

[The moduli space of flat SU (2) and SO (3) connections over surfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044098003271)

[https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~michiel2/docs/thesis.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Emichiel2/docs/thesis.pdf)

Comment: See also:  https://mathoverflow.net/q/201075/12218

Answer (score 11):

Let $K$ be a connected compact Lie group.  The moduli space of flat $K$-bundles over an $n$-torus is homeomorphic to the character variety $Hom(\mathbb{Z}^n,K)/K$.

The identity component of this space is homeomorphic to $T^n/W$ where $T$ is a maximal torus in $K$ and $W$ is the Weyl group (generalizing the example you gave when $K=SU(m)$).

Here are some examples (where $K=SU(2)$):

1. $Hom(\mathbb{Z},K)/K=[-2,2]$
2. $Hom(\mathbb{Z}^2,K)/K=$[image: Pillowcase]
3. $Hom(\mathbb{Z}^3,K)/K$ is a 3-dimensional orbifold.  Here is video of [a continuous family of slices of it.](https://youtu.be/wMj4OBq0HWo)
4. $Hom^0(\mathbb{Z}^2,PSU(2))/PSU(2)=S^2$ as mentioned in Example 3.14 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0781.pdf).  There is one other component and it is a point.

In general, the moduli space is connected iff $n=1$, or $n=2$ and $K$ is simply connected, or $n\geq 3$ and $K$ is isomorphic to a product of $SU(m)$'s and/or $Sp(k)$'s.  And the identity component of the moduli space is simply connected iff $K$ is semisimple (there may be other components that are not simply connected however).  Example 2. above shows that $\pi_2$ may not be trivial even if $K=SU(2)$.

Replacing $K$ with a complex (or real) reductive group $G$, we have a similar, although more complicated story.

Please see my paper: *[Topology of character varieties of Abelian groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7616)* (co-authored with C. Florentino) for details about the reductive case (and references for the above mentioned facts).

Also, for the fundamental group of these moduli spaces please read my paper: *[Fundamental Groups of Character Varieties: Surfaces and Tori](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.4389.pdf)*
 (co-authored with I. Biswas and D. Ramras).